# google app smtp Failed to authenticate laravel 5.2

Tags: php, laravel, email, smtp, host

I'm using Laravel 5.2 and google app for my email . I try connect my website in my google app with smtp but i have this error Failed to authenticate on SMTP server with username "email@domaine.com" using 3 possible authenticators

in my config/mail.php

```
return [
      'driver' => env('MAIL_DRIVER', 'smtp'),
      'host' => env('MAIL_HOST', 'smtp-relay.gmail.com'),
      'port' => env('MAIL_PORT', 587),
      'from' => ['address' => 'email@domaine.com', 'name' => null],
      'encryption' => env('MAIL_ENCRYPTION', 'tls'),
      'username' => 'email@domaine.com',
      'password' => 'mypassword',
      'sendmail' => '/usr/sbin/sendmail -bs',
]
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is your case, but, note that if you have 2 Factor Authentication enabled on your Google Account, **you will have to create an application password** to use in your Laravel application, *your main password won't work*.

Not sure if this is your case though but something like this did happened to me once.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, it was not enought to set the params in the config/mail.php file. I had to set the params in the .env file.

I found this:

```
MAIL_DRIVER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=smtp.mailtrap.io
MAIL_PORT=2525
MAIL_USERNAME=null
MAIL_PASSWORD=null
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=null
```

and I set this instead:

```
MAIL_DRIVER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=smtp.domain.com
MAIL_PORT=587
MAIL_USERNAME=user@domain.com
MAIL_PASSWORD=my_password
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=tls
```

Then it worked.